# List of acronyms from acro package not displaying properly in a IEEEtran double-column document

Tags: ieeetran, acro

I am currently writing an article using the IEEEtran class. I want to use the package `acro` to manage my acronyms and `\printacronyms` to display the acronyms list at the beginning of the article. It usually works fine in a single-column document but in double column the acronym spills over the acronym definition if its too long. Also the acronym on the left column should appear in bold but this is no longer the case with IEEEtran.

Here is a minimum working example

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[template=tabularray]{acro} 

\DeclareAcronym{a}{
    short=aaa,
    long=aaaaa,
}

\DeclareAcronym{b}{
    short=bbbbbbbb,
    long=bbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbb,
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Nomenclature}

\printacronyms  

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]
\ac{a} \ac{b}   
\lipsum[1]  

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: acro]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are two things going on here: 1. [`IEEEtran`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) redefines the standard LaTeX `description` environment which [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) defaults to using, 2. You are unsuccessful in trying to apply the `tabularray` list template.

1. To fix the default [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) list we can
   either redefine the `description` environment or modify the
   [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) list template to use a different
   environment.
   As [`IEEEtran`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) makes the standard LaTeX `description` environment available as `LaTeXdescription` the latter is probably best.
   We can redefine the [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) list description template using

   ```
   \RenewAcroTemplate[list]{description}{%   \acroheading  
   \acropreamble   \begin{LaTeXdescription}
       \acronymsmapF{%
       \item[\acrowrite{short}\acroifT{alt}{/\acrowrite{alt}}]
         \acrowrite{list}%
         \acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{ (}%
         \acroifT{foreign}{\acrowrite{foreign}\acroifT{extra}{, }}%
         \acroifT{extra}{\acrowrite{extra}}%
         \acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{)}%
         \acropagefill
         \acropages
           {\acrotranslate{page}\nobreakspace}
           {\acrotranslate{pages}\nobreakspace}%
       }
       {\item\AcroRerun}   \end{LaTeXdescription} }
   ```

   or to avoid hard-coding the template we can patch it locally when using `\printacronyms`

   ```
   \begingroup
   \let\description\LaTeXdescription
   \let\enddescription\endLaTeXdescription
   \printacronyms  
   \endgroup
   ```

   [image: Compilation showing the acro description list template]
2. Instead to use the `tabularray` list template, we need to do a few
   things. [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) no longer uses package
   options to set things like this, preferring `\acsetup` instead,
   although I'm not sure that `template=tabularray` has ever been a
   valid package option to [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro).

   You should be getting a package warning

   ```
   Package acro Warning: Unknown option `template'
   (acro)                I don't know the option `template'. Please make sure
   (acro)                there is no typo. Check the manual for help.
   ```

   Checking Section 5 Setting options of the
   [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) manual we see
   `\acsetup{<options>}` is preferred. `\acsetup{template=tabularray}`
   yields an error so going to Section 11 Printing the list we see it's
   `\acsetup{list/template=tabularray}`. This yields another error

   ```
   ! Package acro Error: The template `tabularray' needs the package `tabularray'
   (acro)                loaded on line 21
   ```

   which is straightforward, loading the
   [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package the new
   list template is active and compiles successfully.

   [image: Compilation showing the acro tabularray list template]

The following code is compilable for either solution, just comment out `\acsetup{list/template=tabularray}` to get the default description version.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{list/template=tabularray}

\RenewAcroTemplate[list]{description}{%
  \acroheading
  \acropreamble
  \begin{LaTeXdescription}
    \acronymsmapF{%
    \item[\acrowrite{short}\acroifT{alt}{/\acrowrite{alt}}]
      \acrowrite{list}%
      \acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{ (}%
      \acroifT{foreign}{\acrowrite{foreign}\acroifT{extra}{, }}%
      \acroifT{extra}{\acrowrite{extra}}%
      \acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{)}%
      \acropagefill
      \acropages
        {\acrotranslate{page}\nobreakspace}
        {\acrotranslate{pages}\nobreakspace}%
    }
    {\item\AcroRerun}
  \end{LaTeXdescription}
}

\DeclareAcronym{a}{
    short=aaa,
    long=aaaaa,
}

\DeclareAcronym{b}{
    short=bbbbbbbb,
    long=bbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbb,
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Nomenclature}

\printacronyms  

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]
\ac{a} \ac{b}   
\lipsum[1]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried to compile your code but strangely it does not produce a list of acronyms (I am using TeXlive for Ubuntu)

Comment: @Andros I'm guessing you are getting an error `! LaTeX Error: File \`tabularray.sty' not found.` in the log file, it's very important to read and act on errors from compilation. If you've installed TeXLive through the Ubuntu package manager you probably have TeX Live 2020, this pre-dates the [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package and so you cannot use the `tabularray` list template.  Comment out `\usepackage{tabularray}` and `\acsetup{list/template=tabularray}` and use the first solution, or try a different list template.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dai Bowen, it works like a charm! Just a quick question: is it possible to fix the length of each column so that the acronym definitions are aligned?

Comment: @Andros absolutely, the `tabularray` list template would do that, but without the requisite package, check out the `tabular` or `longtable` list templates (the latter requires loading [`longtable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable))

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. I cannot use the tabularray list template as I am using TexLive 2020. My question is: can your first solution be modified such that acronym definitions arealigned the same way acro with the tabularray template would do?

Comment: @Andros perfectly clear, second part of my comment, try `\acsetup{list/template=tabular}` or `\acsetup{list/template=longtable}`.

Comment: I see. `\acsetup{list/template=longtable}`  does not work with a 2-column document. `\acsetup{list/template=tabular}` seems to work on my MWE but it doesn't work on my article as it does not split the acronym list over 2 columns (and I have a big list)

Comment: Yes I am, and I get the following error: **Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144866/discussion-between-dai-bowen-and-andros).